# Difficulty in interpreting the joint probability with conditional probabilities.

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

A, B, and C are events from random variables X, Y, and Z respectively. I am having difficulty in understanding the below formula.

*P(A,B|C) = P(B|C) * P(A|B,C).*

The left hand side of the equation tells - the joint probability of event A and **event B given the occurrence of event C**. However, I am not sure how to interpret the right most term **'P(A|B,C)'**.

Am I supposed to read it as - *'probability of event A **given the occurrences of event B and event C?**,'* i.e., *P(A|(B,C))*

Or am I supposed to read it as - *'joint probability of **event A given the occurrence of event B**, and event C?'* i.e., *P((A|B),C)*

Comment: It is the probability of $A$ given the occurrence of event $B$ and event $C$

Comment: Also, $P((A \mid B), C)$ makes no sense for $A \mid B$ is not an event.

Comment: @WilliamM. Thanks for your answer. With your answer, I realize that all this while I have been reading the left hand side of the equation incorrectly as - joint probability of A and "B given C" i.e., I was treating "B|C" as a new event B1. But, it seems that the right way to read it is - joint probability of A and B, given C.